# Who designed the Python "two snakes" logo?

Tags: logo, branding, python

Here it is, known as the "double snakes" logo and first used in 2005.

http://www.python.org/community/logos/

[image: Python "two snakes" logo]

Comment: Since you [answered your own exact question on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Who-designed-Pythons-logo?srid=hdPPV) 6 years ago, I think you probably know the answer

Comment: @cai Hey! Awesome. I thought I had asked the question before, but I did not know it had been answered. I have no recollection of receiving that answer!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is solely a history question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim Parkin did and discusses the design in this thread (March '06): 
http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t356848-p2-proposed-python-logo.html

cf: https://www.quora.com/Who-designed-Pythons-logo